# Change Look and Feel of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, look-and-feel

How would I go about changing the Look and Feel of a JFrame and Swing components to custom pictures and what not? Is there a set of methods and API's or do I need to just make a custom JFrame that allows me to customize my JFrame further?

I'm trying to get something that looks like the World of Warcraft launcher or League of Legends launcher( best examples i've seen with custom everything xD). I'm pretty new to GUIs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a custom look and feel for Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377694/how-to-create-a-custom-look-and-feel-for-java-swing)

Comment: Not a duplicate that post has not answers. I'm not asking how to do it I'm asking about how to go about it such as is they a prebuilt library or methods to accomplish this task or do I have to create a class that extends JFrame or create a custom class all together...

Comment: That post does have one answer, pointing to the relevant [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/). You can also set various properties on a JFrame such as the icon - see the [JFrame Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160130/custom-swing-look-and-feel-vs-custom-components and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java

Comment: Don't forget to call [`JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated%28boolean%29) if the interest is in the frame itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to the question, but since you're just staring with Java GUI, I'd recommend diving right into JavaFX -- a modern Java UI toolkit.

Please be sure to start with [JavaFX 2.x](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm) -- not JavaFX 1.x, which is basically deprecated.